# Moment JS - how to check if right now is between two time values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

What is the best way of using Moment so that I can check the current time to two time values, a `starttime` and `endtime` of value formats like **10:45** and **20:00**?

So in this example, `starttime` = `10:45` and `endtime` = `20:00`.

If it's 6PM right now (so, 18:00), I want to return true that current time is between starttime and endtime.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Moment JS?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the problems/concerns with your approach?

Comment: moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25');